# Mysql copy all tables into the same database with different name like (tablename_log)

Tags: mysql

I have database it contains around 100 tables and I need to create log table as a copy of the each existing table and append with the `_log` and it is very time consuming to do this manually is there any way to do this by procedure or any other solution?

**Example:**

```
attachments

students

...
```

**need copy of them like below:**

```
attachments_log

students_log

...
```

Comment: Are you aware of CREATE TABLE newtable LIKE oldtable; - but beware indexes and FKs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
select concat('create table ',table_name, '_log like ' , table_name, ';') from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'schemaname';
```

tidy up in notepad - job done (this bit anyway)